# Something in Wordpress or PHP is overriding my access-control-allow-origin header settings

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, cors

I am trying to set my access-control-allow-origin to "*" to get Nostr NIP-05 authentication working from a Wordpress plugin (which I had developed, see: [wp-nostr-nip05](https://github.com/easydns/wp-nostr-nip05))

When I had `nostr.json` hard-coded with my NIP-05 id and the Apache (or Nginx) settings for

`access-control-allow-origin: '*'`

everything worked fine.

Now, when I use the plugin, `nostr.json` is no longer a flat file, it's a PHP script with `force-type` enabled for the `/.well-known/` directory. That way the file can select the appropriate NIP-05 id from the users table, keying on HTTP_HOST and the login name.

Accessing **https://example.com** or **https://example.com/.well-known** yields the expected header, it is only when accessing

**https://example.com/.well-known/nostr.json**

that the access-control-allow-origin is set to:

```
access-control-allow-methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS
access-control-allow-origin: https://example.com, *
access-control-max-age: 1728000
```

Instead of just:

```
access-control-allow-origin: *
```

I think this is causing NIP-05 validation to fail.

I've been looking for places where **access-control-allow-origin** may be getting set explicitly by Wordpress, and found:

```
./httpdocs/wp-includes/rest-api.php
./httpdocs/wp-includes/http.php
```

and commented out:

```
header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . $origin );
header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true' );
```

but that doesn't seem to get it.

Also installed a wordpress plugin to explicitly set the header within wordpress, doesn't change anything

Even tried sending it raw from within **nostr.json**

```
Header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

with no effect.

I'm now officially out of ideas.

Ideally I'd like to be able to just set the "*" in the /.well-known/ directory but I need to get this working first

(Update prompted by comment: There is no .htaccess overriding this, ideally I'd do it all via htaccess but doesn't seem to be taking on this server.)

Update #2: The other thing that is somewhat maddening about this, is that I'm getting different responses from diagnostic tools like:

https://cors-test.codehappy.dev/

which is right now showing me:

```
access-control-allow-methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS
access-control-allow-origin: https://example.com, *
access-control-max-age: 1728000
```

and running something like wget from the command line:

```
$ wget --no-cache --server-response https://example.com/.well-known/nostr.json

 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Server: nginx
  Date: Tue, 11 Apr 2023 15:23:55 GMT
  Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  Connection: keep-alive
  cache-control: public, max-age=2592000
  display: staticcontent_sol
  vary: Accept-Encoding,Origin
  x-middleton-display: staticcontent_sol
  x-powered-by: PHP/8.2.4
  x-sol: pub_site
  Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
  X-Cache-Status: BYPASS
  X-Powered-By: PleskLin
```

But NIP-05 validation still seems to be failing across multiple clients (astral.ninja and Damus) but working on one (snort.social)

Comment: Have you checked if you have an .htaccess in your proyect? That file might override many configurations from your server

Comment: Yes - sorry, I should have mentioned that.

Ideally I'd set this via .htaccess, and it works on cPanel installations where AllowOveride All is the default, but it's trickier on Plesk from the looks of it.

Comment: What response does your WGET request get, if you include an actual `Origin` header? And why is it `Content-Type: text/plain`, when the response is supposed to be JSON?

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe try to specify this in .htaccess

```
<FilesMatch "/.well-known/nostr.json">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</FilesMatch>
```

or you could try to create a new .htaccess file inside well-known folder and add this:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```